# Is there any way to use a wildcard in order to count dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, wildcard, countif

Is there a way to use a wildcard to count the partial string of a date?

In my spreadsheet, I want to use the COUNTIF function to count a certain date. However, the date value also contains the time.

Example: "12/06/2017 17:35:12"

I only want to include "12/06/2017"

This is the formula I have: `=COUNTIF(Pivot_Data[Created Date],"*12/06/2017*")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you must use the "&" concatenation operator on the wildcard symbol instead of including it with the rest of your string. This is specific to the countif and sumif functions:

=COUNTIF(Pivot_Data[Created Date],"*"&"12/06/2017"&"*")

EDIT: Here is a solution for date formats instead of text formats:

=COUNTIFS(Pivot_Data[Created Date],">"&DATEVALUE("12/06/2017"),Pivot_Data[Created Date],"<"&(DATEVALUE("12/06/2017")+1) )

This works because the date is represented as an unique integer in Excel's date encoding, with the time as a decimal value.

Comment: This still returns 0, this was one of the many methods I used trying to solve this perviously

Comment: In that case I'd wager it has to do with formatting (i.e. the cell being formatted as a date instead of text). Let me see if I can replicate this issue.

Comment: The pivot table i'm using as the range was generated by a query in VSTS if that helps.

Comment: Just updated my answer, but I see that  ImaginaryHuman072889 had essentially the same idea. You may want to update your question with a more detailed explanation of your setup if it is causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Place * either side of the date.E.g. =COUNTIF(E9,"*12/06/2017*")

This is a wildcard match. Adjust range according to needs.

Comment: How is this different from OPs formula?

Comment: Apologies, the asterisks made the text Italic. This returns a value of 0.

Comment: OP asked what the wildcard character was. Example given.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching for a specific text, I would just check if the date is the same as Excel's built in serial number. Also I prefer `SUMPRODUCT` over `COUNTIF`.

Something like:

```
= SUMPRODUCT((FLOOR(Pivot_Data[Created Date],1)=DATE(2017,12,6))+0)
```

The `FLOOR` function (in this case) effectively just takes the date and removes any reference to what time it is on that date.

I think this way is better because it doesn't rely on the cell being a specific text format.

See below, I used this formula but replaced `Pivot_Data[Created Date]` with `A1:A5` just to demonstrate that this formula works with sample data. As expected, the formula returns a value of `2` because the data contains two dates on 12/6/2017. Notice how it doesn't care what time it is.

[image]

Comment: This formula still returns a 0. Strangely enough, inputting the full string "12/06/2017 17:35:12" returns the correct value.

Comment: Not sure why it isn't working. See my answer again. I edited the answer to show that it works on my spreadsheet with sample data.

Comment: Still doesn't work, perhaps it could be that the range is a Pivot Table on a seperate sheet? Although, I've not encountered a problem like this whilst using the same database. Or perhaps it could be my works machine causing problems?

Comment: Doubtful that it's something specific to your machine. It may be because of the pivot table. I'm not that familiar with pivot tables in general. If it is on a different sheet, perhaps try specifying the sheet in front of the table name. (e.g. `Sheet1!Pivot_Data[Created Date]`). If that doesn't work, not sure.

Comment: This still returns 0. I'd be inclined to believe it is the pivot table, but it's strange that it returns the full string and not the partial string.

Comment: You could just take the pivot table out of the equation entirely to see if that fixes the issue, i.e. replace `Pivot_Data[Created Data]` with the actual data range (for example `Sheet1!A1:E10` if that is the actual data range).